# How to do getenv for a value stored in a char* string variable

Tags: c, getenv

a char * var = "EnvVariable";
this EnvVariable is stored in env variable example (EnvVariable="test")

now we want to get the value of EnvVariable in char *result .

when print result it will give me output of EnvVariable i.e test.

Comment: you mean like `result = getenv(var)` ?

Comment: Search for "examples of getenv() in C" on the net. The code is out there for you! :)

Comment: this will not able to compile,

Comment: If you put it into correct context (which you did not show us) it will compile. What did you try so far and where do you have a problem? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a detailled description of any problem. If you get an error, show complete and exact message. All text (code, input, output, warning, errors) shouls be included as formatted text directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this exemple :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    const char * path = getenv( "PATH" );
    printf( "PATH environment variable == %s\n", path );

    return 0;
}
```